# Not getting the phone number response field with google contact API version 3.0

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I tried with below google contacts API

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?q=john&v=3.0&alt=json

With this I'm getting email(gd:email) and name(gd:email) but I'm not getting the phone number. But as per the API I should get the **gd:phonenumber** as well.

I saw similar queries but I didn't come across the solution.

I need to get the basic email and phone numbers of my contacts.

Comment: Any suggestion on this.

Comment: It was specified in the [Contacts API documentation](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/) that "for read and write access to users' contacts, use the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people), which provides both contact and profile information using JSON instead of the older GData protocol". Check this option to get through.

Comment: But with People API, For authenticated person I can get the deatils(like me), but If I check want to check any of my contact persons phoneNumber I need their account_id to query with people api which I could not get.

When I use my personal gmail I'm able to get the phoneNumber but within my organisation we are using gmail for business with my organisation  ID I'm not able to get the my contact's phoneNumbers. contact API not returning

Comment: contats API reads from what the current authenticated user has added to https://contacts.google.com people API also checks Google plus but plus dosent return non-public phone numbers even for the current authenticated user.   what do you mean by account id

Comment: With People API, https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get need to provide resourceName - **people/me** (For self authenticated) or other contacts need to provide their **people/account_id**.  But here I could not get the other persons  account_id. This account_id might be called also with userId or profileId. Without this ID I can't get the phoneNumber.  Is there any way to get the email address and phone Numbers? with contact API or people API

Comment: Is there a way to get the email and phone numbers of my contacts..

Comment: Could anyone suggest on this.!

Comment: Still looking to get my contact's phone number and email address with Google apis

Comment: When I see , Directory profile - Work,Mobile,Work,Birthday,Manager,Department,Description,Organization.
I have these details. 
G-suite Admin SDK, https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users with this API, can I use this to get the details, Now actually I'm getting not authorized to access.

Comment: how can we get the organization contacts, we are using google as business. I want to get the contacts. I gone through Contacts API v3 - https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/ (giving me not full contacts of my organisation), People API - people/connections(here I'm getting only my details not showing the ) , G Suite Admin SDK -> Directory API - users.list (giving me not authorized to access but I already given proper scope and admin setting enabled to my app),  G Suite Admin SDK -> Domain Shared Contacts API . 
Out of these what will give all of my organisation contacts.